# Зависимости приложения, названия пакетов (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Хочу собрать .deb пакет для своей программы.
Так выглядит список зависимостей:

```
Depends: libcurl3,libpcre3,libssl1.0.0,
libgoogle-glog0,libboost-filesystem1.54.0,libboost-system1.54.0
```

1. Что означают эти цифры в конце названия "3", "0" ?
2. Почему в названиях пакетов boost явно указана версия (1.54.0). А что будет, когда появятся новые версии буста? Эта версия исчезнет? Как долго она будет в репах?

У меня уже было такое, что пакет внезапно куда-то пропадал (например, openssl 0.9) и программа просто не устанавливалась. Как правильно "готовить" пакет для Ubuntu?

Comment: Гуглится за полторы секунды: http://habrahabr.ru/post/78094/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ на *часть* поднятых вопросов.

мне известна по крайней мере одна из причин включения номера версии в название пакета: когда в новой версии «ломается» обратная совместимость.

пример — упомянутый `boost`. начиная с версии 1.35 было принято решение включать версию в имя пакета, для того чтобы в репозитории присутствовали несколько версий пакетов `*boost*` и продолжали работать те пакеты, которые зависят от «старой» версии. см. обсуждение в сообщении об ошибке [#473752](http://bugs.debian.org/473752).

> Как долго она будет в репах?

пока в репозитории есть пакеты, которые не работают с новой версией.

чаще всего это означает, что такие пакеты «заброшены» сопровождающими, так что они становятся кандидатами на удаление в новой версии дистрибутива.

Comment: Тогда наверно стоит статически линковаться с бустом, чтобы избежать проблем в будущем?

Comment: @zenden2k, боюсь, по этому поводу не смогу ничего подсказать. лишь приведу ссылки на [*debian policy* по поводу *static linking*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html) и на [*debian wiki* по этому же поводу](https://wiki.debian.org/StaticLinking). а вообще, конечно, всё зависит от цели сборки пакета: индивидуальное использование, собственный репозиторий (для, например, клиентов), включение пакета в официальный репозиторий и т.п.